# Flutter - How to remove margin under GridView?

Tags: flutter, dart

I get a strange margin under my `GridView`:

[image: IOS example]

This image is from an IOS simulator, here's how it looks on a smaller screen on Android where the margin appears to be gone or a lot smaller:

[image: Android example]

Here's the code:

```
Column(
  children: [
     GridView.count(
       shrinkWrap: true,
       crossAxisCount: 8,
       children: tiles
     ),
     Text('mamma')
  ]
)
```

Each element in the grid (`tiles`) is an `EmptyTile` widget:

```
class EmptyTile extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: bgColor,
        border: Border.all(color: borderColor)
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I really can't figure out what this margin is or where it comes from, whether it has something to do with `shrinkWrap` or something else.

How can I remove this margin?

**EDIT:**

As requested here's the fullscreen images without the simplified example.

IOS:

[image: IOS]

Android:

[image: Android]

Comment: it seems like a portion of the whole screen. can you post a full-screen image for android and iOS?

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi Added them. I won't add the code for the full example since it's quite a lot and doesn't add anything to the problem as it still appears just with the simple `Text` widget. I hope this adds some clarity.

Answer (score 13):

Try this. by default it has padding and you should set padding to zero.

```
 GridView.builder(
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference in layout you experience comes from a combination of things:

- How `GridView` manages its size.
- How widgets are placed in a `Column`.

### GridView tiles and size

When you build a `GridView`, its width and height are implicitly deduced from the `crossAxisCount` parameter and the constraints given by its parent.

The constraints are the limits in size in which the widget is allowed to draw.

The `crossAxisCount` defines how many tiles should fit in one line (row or column). Depending on its `scrollDirection`, it will either try to fill all the available width or height. By default this direction is set to `Axis.vertical`, which means that the width will be filled.

So when we come back to your example, this means that the size of each tile will depend on the width of the `Column` containing your grid, divided by the number of tiles you set in `crossAxisCount`. This size will be both the width and the height of every tile in your `GridView`.

Once Flutter knows the size of each of your tiles, it sets them on each row, until all tiles are placed or there isn't any available space.

### Column layout

Now that we know more about `GridView`, we need to understand how `Column` builds its layout.

Columns allocates space to each widget in its children, following [an algorithm best describes in the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html).

tl;dr:
Your `GridView` will only fill its own height in the `Column`, leaving the rest as free space. This is why you get empty space in your Column.

### Possible fix

I actually don't really see how this is a problem. GridViews are supposed to only extend to display their children, so it totally makes sense for it to stop when it completed.

The thing is, most of the times this ind of grids are not used with a finite list of children, and more likely with a growing list.

If you only want to have one line of tiles, that will extend using the available space, you could use a simple Row.

If you want multiple lines of tiles, with non-square tiles, you need to dive a little deeper into `GridView.custom`.

**Edit after question was updated with more screenshots:**

It is possible that you need to rethink your layout so that the player panels are in the same `Column` than the game board. You will have a much better control over the layout this way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I kinda understand what the problem is now. The player panels are in the same column, just excluded from the simplified example. How would I control the tile sizes if I use a single `Row`? The tiles needs to fill the available space horizontally and then get the same height as its width, since `GridView` takes care of this automatically I'm unsure how to achieve this in the most efficient way. Any pointers?

Comment: you could try `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,` inside the main `Column`

Comment: You could probably try wrapping you player panels in Flexible widget, so that they will take all the space available to them. You can also add Padding widgets to the top and bottom of your Column if you don't want your player panels to extend to the top and bottom of your layout.

Comment: @HarshvardhanJoshi Made it worse unfortunately :P

Comment: I think this will take some trial and error for getting desired result.. thanks for letting me know btw

Comment: @Jquenel Didn't work using `Flexible`, the Grid still leaves that margin. I want to use a Row but not sure how to make the tiles in the board a square without hardcoding a width/height.

Comment: Sorry if I answer too late, I had no internet access during the holidays.
I'm not sure how Flexible didn't work for you, unless you wrapped the wrong thing... Maybe try something that would look like this ?

 Flexible(Container()), 

Player(), 

Grid(), 

Player(), 

Flexible(Container())